# Is DirectShow capable of cuting out some parts of the video?

Tags: directshow, video-processing, directshow.net

I got no experience in video processing API and I have hard time finding answer for this question. My aim is to create program capable of creating video from chosen parts of selected file. I could not find answer if DirectShow is capable of removing some parts of the video or cuting out some of the parts to merge them into new, shorter video.

Answer (score 1):

DirectShow Editing Services (DES) is exactly what you're asking about. This is basically the engine of Windows Movie Maker and it was part of DirectShow since DirectX 8. There you can create timeline with one or many video and audio tracks, put parts of one or different files there and then either play or render it to a file. It even supports rendering without recompression, for some formats. DES was available for many years but now is considered obsolete.

In pure DirectShow it's still possible by using IMediaSeeking interface on proper output pins to seek to desired start point and process desired parts of files.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, DirectShow cannot do it out of the box. It seems like you are developing a video editing application. First you should develop a player that will provide a way to play from-to (in time or frame units) and to be able to play frame-by-frame.  With such player user will be able to select fragments of his choice. One way of doing it would be to develop decoding part with or without DShow and rendering part with DShow, because it's easier. The rendering part would probably require a custom source filter connected to audio and/or video renderer. Such custom source filter should have custom interface for configuration and for receiving uncompressed data. The decoding part should have previously mentioned features for playing fragments and stepping frame-by-frame, so you can control the playback and provide selection for frame accurate file fragments (for later export to one file).

The second part of the application would be for creating a new video file from selected fragments. You have 2 options here. You can re-encode all of these fragments. By doing that you will lose quality. Also, you will have to configure the encoder first by telling him what is the input and what is the output format. Depending on selected encoder this could be either trivial or rather complex. The second option is to create a new video from the compressed samples. Here you will have to pay attention to start such file with a key frame (for video stream). Also you will need a third party SDK for such task, or you can do it manually if you are familiar with the resulting container format architecture. For example, Windows Media Format SDK provides a way for doing that if your source format is ASF/WMV file. If not, regarding video, you will have to solve it somehow.

IF you are about to do this, prepare yourself for a considerable amount of coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer man. The biggest problem is that I've never ever even worked with video manipulation libraries. Second biggest is that I need to do this using C# so wrappers are the way to go, as all of available non-commercial libraries are C++ ones. ATM whole topic is quite abstract to me, I dont even know where to start.

I knew about the player part but what I thought is that fiding proper library capable of cuting is more important. That's why I decided to ask about DirectShow capabilities first.

Comment: C++ is much better option for low level audio/video processing. For writing DirectShow filters as well. You can use C# for putting all that together and UI. Beware of non-commercial C++ libraries. Authors of such libraries are changing the interface very often. As a result you will have serious problems when switching to newer version. DirectShow will definitely help you on your way, but you will have to do some extra coding. Also, keep on your mind that MS plans to retire DirectShow. Crappy Media Foundation is the replacement. (At least it was meant to be)

Comment: And what's the biggest difference between MF and DS at the moment? Besides Microsoft dumping DS and supporting Media Foundation as it's replacement?

Comment: MF still contains many bugs. For example, you cannot write some complicated playback application with everything that MF offers, because some things are still broken. I also had contacts with MS regarding that and for some things they said how they have no idea, for some other things they confirmed bugs in their code etc...  IMHO, the big problem is very bad documentation. There is also a MF book, but the author (Anton Polinger) simply printed what's on the MSDN, nothing more. Generally, the MF architecture is very bad from my point of view.